# Symfony2 + Doctrine2 SQL Integrity Violation: Nullable field can't be null?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

So this project is moving some straight PDO SQL queries (with MySQL) to Doctrine. The tables already existed and had data in them. I set up the entities, and everything seemed golden. All the queries were rewritten with the Entity Manager in Doctrine, and everything seemed to work.

Except I forgot that three fields in one of the entities needed to be nullable. They were set to NOT NULL in the database and there was no nullable=true declaration in the Doctrine annotations.

I manually altered to table in MySQL to make the fields nullable, then added a nullable=true to the entities, cleared the cache and executed a

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Just to be sure (which executed correctly).

However, despite the fact that the Doctrine entity allows null fields, and the database has the columns nullable as well, I still get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'type_id' cannot be null
```

Is there any way for me to fix this without dropping the tables (which would involve also saving all the data)? What exactly is wrong here? According to all the code and databases involved, there should be no integrity violations at all (the field isn't a foreign key either).

Here is the entity in question:

```
class Audio
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="id")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="type", columnDefinition="ENUM('song','demo')")
     */
    protected $type;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="type_id", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $typeId = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="s3_url", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $s3url = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="s3_key", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $s3key = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", name="date_created")
     */
    protected $dateCreated;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", name="date_modified")
     */
    protected $dateModified;
```

This is absolutely mystifying me. There's really no more ways for me to tell the program that it can be null.

Comment: Did you cleare cache? If so, ensure that your schema is really as you're expecting (with: "show create table Audio"). BTW Don't make changes manually in database - let doctrine to do that.

Comment: Yes, I cleared the cache (as I mentioned in the post) and I ran the schema update as well.

Comment: Ok, and when you run "show create table Audio" (from mysql console), there is not "not null" next to type_id column?

Comment: (and the easy way would be: 1) create db dump: "mysqldump -uUSER --password="PASSWORD" DBNAME > dump.sql" 2) RECREATE database using doctrine 3) load dump)

Comment: use doctrine migrations to compare the difference. You can actually manually alter the SQL in the generated migration version file to make sure `type_id` allow null.

Comment: The program knows that it can be null - the database does not.

That error is coming from MySQL, not from Doctrine.

Comment: @madebydavid No, manual db inserts from the command line allowed nulls. I ended up fixing this by writing a complex migration script that rebuilt the tables another time and saved the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi i don't know if you still have the problem.

You can do `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`
In order to know the difference bewteen your model and the database.
And apply the line he will tell you.

I think it will fix the problem